How can I perform hostname verification with a multiplatform Ktor Socket connection?
I am rewriting our Java api service in Kotlin Multiplatform, and working on a replacement for javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket to send and receive data between the server and client.
I've been using the Ktor Socket to do this, and it's been perfect until this point.
This is how we performed hostname verification in the Java code:
if (hostNameVerification) {
    val hostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()
    val sslSession = sslSocket!!.session

    // Verify that the certificate hostname is for ****.com
    // This is due to lack of SNI support in the current SSLSocket.
    if (!hostnameVerifier.verify(connectionConfig.domain, sslSession)) {
        throw SSLHandshakeException("Expected ****.com, found ${sslSession.peerPrincipal}")
    }
 }

Of course, the HttpsURLConnection and HostnameVerifier classes aren't available in multiplatform code.
I've looked through the Ktor documentation for Sockets, but no mention of hostname verification. I asked ChatGPT, and got this answer:
Since Ktor doesn’t abstract SSL/TLS handling for sockets directly in a multiplatform way, you’ll have to manage the verification process using platform-specific implementations.
I would just like to know if that answer is true, or if there is some way to handle verification in a multiplatform way. If it's not possible, I would like some input on how to handle verification for jvm and native environments separately.

The original idea of checking that you've got a specific wrong certificate (since no SNI was used) seems to be wrong from start. Don't try to replicate it. If the certificate is correct than there is no need to have such a custom verifier at all.

The ChatGPT is right. You can follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4085 for updates.
